# Cached Images not shown in Product Image (CDN at AWS S3)

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, aws, cdn

I am stuck here. As i am using S3 bucket and S3FS-FUSE for syncing my /media folder with S3 bucket with rsync (cronjob).

As rsync is very slow in syncing cached images with S3, thus it results in broken image links on main product pages as cached images are not present in S3.

This is actually a known problem with the CDN, i am also not able to figure out any workout.

Is it possible to modify some code in magento 1.9.3.4 for **MAIN PRODUCT IMAGE**, that magento will load only original images from CDN S3, not the cached images.